# The best way to execute copy constructor using .Copy?

Tags: c++, string, object, copy-constructor

I need help executing this copy constructor in my object oriented program. The result should be to copy string 1: `Hello World` into string 2: `This is a test`.

**In my `.h` file**:

```
void Copy(MyString& one);
```

**In my `.cpp` file**:

```
void MyString::Copy(MyString& one)
{
   one = String;
}
```

**In my `main.cpp` file**:

```
String1.Print();
cout  << endl;
String2.Print();
cout  << endl;      
String2.Copy(String1);      
String1.Print();       
cout  << endl;
String2.Print();
cout  << endl;
```

**The output**:

```
Hello World
This is a test
is a test
This is a test
```

**It should be**:

```
Hello World
This is a test
Hello World
Hello World
```

Please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Here is my entire .cpp file:

```
MyString::MyString()

{

char temp[] = "Hello World";

        int counter(0);
        while(temp[counter] != '\0') {
                counter++;
        }
        Size = counter;
        String = new char [Size];
        for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)
                String[i] = temp[i];

}

MyString::MyString(char *message)

{

      int counter(0);

       while(message[counter] != '\0') {

      counter++;

   }

        Size = counter;

        String = new char [Size];


         for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)

           String[i] = message[i];

}

MyString::~MyString()

{

        delete [] String;

}

int MyString::Length()

{
              int counter(0);

              while(String[counter] != '\0')
             {
                     counter ++;
             }

                return (counter);
}

void MyString:: Set(int index, char b)

{

         if(String[index] == '\0')

          {
                   exit(0);
          }

         else

        {

                   String[index] = b;
          }


}

void MyString::Copy(MyString& one)

{

        one = String;


}

char MyString:: Get(int i)
{

             if( String[i] == '\0')
             {
                     exit(1);
             }
            else
            {

                    return String[i];

            }
}



void MyString::Print()

{

        for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)

            cout << String[i];

             cout << endl;


}
```

Comment: `void MyString::Copy` is a member function, not a copy constructor. A copy constructor would have a signature `MyString::MyString(const MyString& other)`, and no return type at all, not even `void`.

Comment: Here is my instructions per my professor: The MyString object should have a Copy(...) method that copies one object into another one....am I getting the 2 confused?

Comment: @user964141 Yes, a Copy method is not the same thing as a copy constructor.

Comment: No, the instructions are right: `Copy(...)` can be called a *method* (and that's what it is called in the rest of the object-oriented world, but in C++ it's called a member function). But `Copy` is not a constructor.

Comment: There are way many things that are wrong with your code, you should learn to use standard library containers and algorithms. Calculating the length of a C-string can be as simple as `strlen( ptr )`, you should use `const` much more often for example the `Set` function does not modify the object. Regarding this function's implementation checks that you don't overwrite the null terminator, but it does not check that that the index is valid (i.e. in the range `[0..Size)`), either provide a full check or none at all. `Length` recalculates the value of `Size`...

Comment: Your `Copy` method doesn't actually *copy* the string! It just assigns the object to point to the other object's string, which is totally different.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Actually I think a copy is made. `out = String` where out is a MyString and String is a char const * results in a MyString being constructed with MyString(char const *), and then the compiler generated copy assignment operator is used. And then that temporary MyString is destroyed, deleting the copy of the char const * and leaving out with a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`void Copy(MyString& one);` isn't a copy constructor, but I guess all you need is a function that does copying.

The implementation:

```
void MyString::Copy(MyString& one) {
   one = String;
}
```

This is taking `String`, whatever that is, presumably your classes internal storage, and assigning it the string you pass in...

That means that `String2.Copy(String1)` is like doing `String1 = String2.String`. Your desired output indicates that you want to copy String1 into String2 but you're going the completely wrong direction.

Additionally, the fact that this assignment results in a partial copy ("is a test") means that however you're doing that assignment is broken too. You don't show the implementation of that so I can't tell you how it's broken.

---

There are many issues with the code. You should probably go over it with another student or a TA. But for the specific issues your output shows you should look at three things. First google 'the rule of three'. Second consider what '=' means when the left side is a `MyString` object and the right side is char*. Third, once you've figured out how exactly the data will be copied, reverse the direction of assignment (e.g., `*this = out.String`) so that you're copying in the right direction.

Comment: @user964141 You can edit your question above to add your code.